# If object is private but its lookup allows Read, what will happen?

Tags: permissions, sharing, org-wide-defaults, fls

What will be the access level for the lookup field in these 2 scenarios:

1. MyObject is private, object-level permissions allow Read, and lookup to MyObject allows Read
2. Same as 1 but object-level permissions don't allow Read

I believe FLS takes precedence, so the field should be readable in both cases, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FLS does not override object visibility. If you can't see an object, you can't see a field that references the object. Neither does object permissions automatically grant permission to field(s) that reference the object. This is case, both permissions are restrictive. Only in the first case would the field be readable.

Comment: I swear on my DEV401 exam I was asked this question multiple times and as far as I can remember the FLS overrode the object permissions. Example: MyObject is not readable but MyObject.Field1 is readable, therefore Field1 is readable. I know this is different than my original question, but it still shows FLS takes priority over object permissions.. Or am I completely mistaken thanks to potentially faulty prep material?

Comment: Sounds like bad material. I tested the scenario before I posted this answer to make sure I was right. Hiding an object hides all related lists, fields, and tabs related to the object for that profile.